# Change X and Y position of images on sliding for collage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am Refering this app ass reference i want to make collage in which i can increase X-Y position of images by sliding the sliders given below. How can i achieve this functionality.?

[image: REF Image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this: in interface declare uiimageview instance:

```
@interface myViewController
{
    UIImageView *myImage;
}
```

Or added it through xib-file. Then add

```
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender;
```

to h.file and implement it:

```
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender
{
     UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
     int scaleFactor =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);

     CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor); // example
     myImage.transform = scale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface myViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIIMageView *myImage;
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider1;
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider2;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   slider1.tag=101;
   slider2.tag=102;
}
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(UISlider*) sender
{
     int x,y;

  switch (sender.tag) {
        case 101:
           x=(int)(slider1.value + 0.5f);
            break;
         case 102:
           y=(int)(slider2.value + 0.5f);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
     CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x, y); 
     myImage.transform = scale;
}
```

Good luck!!!